# Get last Modified Date of Files in a directory

Tags: java, android, file

I am having some trouble displaying the files currently modified date.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String dir = "/FileDirectory/";

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dir);

private final Activity context;

Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified()); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModified); 

private String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView text;
}

public MyAdapter(Activity context, String[] date) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, date);
    this.context = context;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.FilePath);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    String s = formattedDateString;

    holder.text.setText(s);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

As of now it just displays the last modified date of the directory on all files.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it is just doing the right thing

Comment: How can I fix it so it displays the modified date for each file separately?

Comment: You can go through my way to get the last modified time of a directory @user2250122

Answer (score 11):

In your question, you are pointing a Directory, not a File.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dir);


private final Activity context;

Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified()); 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModified);
```

The idea is to get a Directory and iterate searching for the Last modified date of all files. The following question may help:
[How to get only 10 last modified files from directory using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005965/how-to-get-only-10-last-modified-files-from-directory-using-java?rq=1)

**EDIT 1:**

My Tricky Solution:

```
File images = new File("YourDirectoryPath");
long[] fileModifieDate = new long[images.listFiles().length];
int i=0;

        File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {

            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                File file = new File(dir, name);
                fileModifieDate[i++] = file.lastModified();
                return true;
            }

        });
// Here, max is the last modified date for this directory 
// Here, Long array **fileModifieDate** will give modified time of all files, which you can also access from Files array
// if you want the last modified file in the directory you can do this:


        File[] maxModifiedDate = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {

            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                File file = new File(dir, name);

                return file.lastModified() == max;
            }

        });

// Now **maxModifiedDate** File array will have only one File, which will have max modified date.
```

**EDIT 2:**

For your case, this would be helpful:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String dir = "/FileDirectory/";

File myFolder= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dir);
if(myFolder.exists()){


    File[] filelist = myFolder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {

        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {  
            return true;
        }

    }); 
}
```

// Now you have a **filelist** array of Files. If you want lastModified data, you can fetch from each individual file as you were doing previously:

```
  private final Activity context;

    Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified()); 
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
    String formattedDateString = formatter.format(lastModified); 

    private String dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Well what I am wanting is to display when each of the files was modified in a list.  It is not a big deal to me if they are sorted correctly.

Comment: @user2250122 : i think from List of files you can get the lastModified date of all files see updated answer which clarifies and list all modified date for all files in directory

Comment: whats the problem just change the path as per your requirement

Comment: I need to hook it into my array of files.

Comment: coz now you have array of file now you can get all files property available

Comment: It looks like it will work, so I up-voted it, but I'm having a tough time integrating it in my code. Do you know exactly how I would integrate it?  As always, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user2250122 : Sorry i think you should integrate with your self as much as i could help i did see update 2

Answer (score 3):

Complete code to get the last modified date

```
    File file = new File("c:\\test\\myfile.txt");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Modified Date :- " + sdf.format(file.lastModified()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dir);`

Points to directory, not a file.

If you need modified date of each file separately in a directory, just use **walkfiletree**.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer of Anonymous Mohit, but it only checks the file size of items inside the folder. But what if there are many subfolders? Here's how I did it.

```
public static long lastModifiedDate;
public static long getLastModified(String path) {
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if(GlobalValues.DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "Get last modified date: " + path);
    if (files.length == 0) return directory.lastModified();
    else {
        for(File filesInFolder: files) {
            if(filesInFolder.isDirectory()) {
                getLastModified(filesInFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                if(lastModifiedDate == 0) {
                    lastModifiedDate = filesInFolder.lastModified();
                } else{
                    if(filesInFolder.lastModified() >= lastModifiedDate){
                        lastModifiedDate = filesInFolder.lastModified();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin implementation:

```
fun getLastModified(path: String): Long {

    val directory = File(path)
    var dirTS = directory.lastModified()

    val listFilesAndSubDirs = directory.listFiles()
    if (listFilesAndSubDirs.isEmpty()){
        return dirTS
    }

    for (file in listFilesAndSubDirs) {
        val itemTS = if (file.isDirectory) {
           getLastModified(file.path)
        } else {
           file.lastModified()
        }

        if (itemTS > dirTS){
            return itemTS
        }
    }

    return dirTS
}
```