# getting the last file between files with java program

Tags: java

How do I find the last modified file in a directory with java?
get file name of last file modified java 
EXP: i have:
test_4755_err.log.
test_4588_err.log.
test_14587_err.log.`
i wanna get thé last file between this files

Comment: Can you at least capitalize your sentences?

Comment: what about scan all files and check?

Comment: When posting on stackoverflow for a question like this, you need to show what you have currently tried, and why it does not presently work. If you have already attempted to solve the problem, please go ahead and post your current solution.

Comment: check out this link if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803675/get-last-modified-date-of-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Files.getLastModifiedTime(directory) should work for directory too

Comment: @PaulRichter I tried but i don't have result if you want i send you my code Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for the file that was last modified? You could do:

```
File lastModified = null;
String directory = "."; // replace with your directory
File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles();
if(files != null){
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(File o, File t){
            // reverse the ordering so the newest file is first in the array
            return -1 * Long.compare(o.lastModified(), t.lastModified());
        }
    });
    lastModified = files[0];
}
```

As pointed out, this would be more efficient:

```
File newest = null
for(File f : new File(dir).listFiles()){
    if(newest == null || f.lastModified() > newest.lastModified()){
        newest = f;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're just looking for the newest file or the oldest file, it's wasteful to bring all of them into an array and sort them. You could just iterate over the files and keep the newest-so-far. Iterating over the files is O(n), while sorting them is O(nlogn).