# Java Code to Fetch the Latest Folder Name in a Directory

Tags: java, selenium

Am new to Java and seeking your help here.

I have a Parent Folder/Directory Named as : DP_E2E_POC
Under the Parent Folder i have many sub Folders, i need to find the latest Folder Name under the Parent Folder.

Example: 
[image]

from the image attached i need to fetch the latest folder which is "DELTA_DP_E2E_POC_ManualBuild_20161128.1"

Thanks in Advance,
Satish D

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last Modified Date of Files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803675/get-last-modified-date-of-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @Biffen - My Question is: How to fetch the latest Folder name under a Parent Folder?

Comment: @Imesha - I dont need to get the last Mdified Date of Files, I need the name of the Folder which is latest under a parent folder

Comment: Get the list of folders in the directory and sort it by timestamp and get the folder name.

Comment: @SatishDhanaraj But the approach is the same. Even the class name we use is `File`, it can check for directories too. Look at @Saravana 's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the last modified to sort the directories and get the latest one

```
    File dir = new File("path");
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    File lastModified = Arrays.stream(files).filter(File::isDirectory).max(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified)).orElse(null);
    System.out.println(lastModified);
```

using for loop

```
    File dir = new File("/path");
    File max = null;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory() && (max == null || max.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
            max = file;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent the code using loop worked like a charm for me... Thank you so much