# Java 1.8 compilation error for lastmodified

Tags: java, filestream, last-modified

```
File lastModified = Arrays.stream(files)
    .filter(File::isDirectory)
    .max(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified))
    .orElse(null)
```

Can the above code changed to be compatible for 1.7?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143684/can-java-8-code-be-compiled-to-run-on-java-7-jvm and https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided `files instanceof File[]`, it should be smth like that:

```
private static File getFileLastModified(File[] files) {
    File fileLastModified = null;
    long maxLastModified = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            final long lastModified = file.lastModified();
            if (lastModified > maxLastModified) {
                fileLastModified = file;
                maxLastModified = lastModified;
            }
        }
    }
    return fileLastModified;
}
```

In short, it tries to find the last modified file.

Comment: Worked like a champ

Answer (score 0):

No, Stream API is available only from Java 8

*upd:* You can find a file with the most recent changes with a for loop. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064694/how-do-i-find-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-in-java) post

Comment: Well, you can rewrite the code to achieve the same implementation with Java 1.7

Comment: With a for loop of course, but not using Stream API